# Error setting up Azure Continuous Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, continuous-integration, azure-web-roles

I keep getting this error everytime I try to setup TFS plublishing with my Azure Cloud Services Account:

> Unable to find AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml

And links to this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/06/07/announcing-continuous-deployment-to-azure-with-team-foundation-service.aspx

I had removed the BuildProcessTemplates folder to another path inside TFS. I just restored it to "$//BuildProcessTemplates" just like the article said, but I keep getting the same error from the Windows Azure Management portal.

The publishing templates haven't been modified.

Comment: This error still occurs in the **Azure Portal**, but the build template name it's looking for is actually `TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml` for TFS 2013. See [related SO post regarding linking **Azure Cloud Service** with **VSO**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27611902/175679).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so apparently, I needed at least one Build Configuration defined in the "Builds" section of Team Explorer for this to work.

I added a new configuration called TEMP and directed the process template xaml to the root folder.

Once that was configured I went back to the Azure Management Site, retried the "Setup TFS Publishing" option and everything worked fine.

Comment: thanks! this sent me down the right track. I had to create the new temp build definition as well as add back in each process template in my BuildProcessTemplates folder on the source root...did that from the Process tab by clicking the New button and selecting each template from that folder...including the AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml