# Azure Continuous Deployment - Setup Publishing with VSO

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-cloud-services

We've been able to setup [Azure Continuous Deployment](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254710) with some [VSO Team Projects](http://www.visualstudio.com/), but not others. Any idea why we are getting this error in the [Azure Management Portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com)? Perhaps it depends on the age of the team project.

> Unable to find **AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml** in **TeamProject** see [[Link]](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/06/07/announcing-continuous-deployment-to-azure-with-team-foundation-service.aspx)

[image]

We've followed the [directions suggested](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/06/07/announcing-continuous-deployment-to-azure-with-team-foundation-service.aspx):

#### Integrating Azure Continuous Integration with VSO

1. Add **Build Template** `AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml` to `$/[TeamProject]/BuildProcessTemplate`
2. Created **Build Definition** in [TeamProject] referencing `AzureContinuousDeployment.11.xaml` in Step 1 (*i.e. Registering the Template*)
3. Proceed with "Set up publishing with Visual Studio Online". Enter VSO host and select [TeamProject].

I can see there are connected services under the **[Team Project]** in VSO (*under Team Project Admin -> Services*).
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the Azure Portal/VSO error message needs updated to reflect new **Azure Continuous Deployment** updates for **TFS 2013** (*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client*).

#### Proper Error Message

> Unable to find **TfvcContinuousDeploymentTemplate.12.xaml** in [TeamProject] see [Link]

The fix is to upload the TFS 2013 Azure CD template and create a build definition to *register* the template with the [TeamProject].

This is only necessary for older VSO projects that don't get the default Azure CD build template.